# Finding Min , 2nd min , 3rd min and so on for each rows of SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a situation where I am required to find min then 2nd min then 3rd min and so on for each row based on a common key attributes

**Table 1 (Qty>=1)**

```
╔═══════════════════╗
║ Item Location Qty ║
╠═══════════════════╣
║ 500    Loc1     5 ║
║ 501    Loc2     2 ║
║ 501    Loc3     1 ║
╚═══════════════════╝
```

**Table 2 (Qty always 1)**

```
╔══════════════════════════╗
║ Item Location Qty Asset  ║
╠══════════════════════════╣
║ 500    Loc1      1   11  ║
║ 500    Loc1      1   12  ║
║ 500    Loc1      1   13  ║
║ 500    Loc1      1   14  ║
║ 500    Loc1      1   15  ║
║ 500    Loc1      1   10  ║
║ 500    Loc1      1    9  ║
║ 500    Loc1      1    8  ║
║ 500    Loc1      1    7  ║
║ 501    Loc2      1    27 ║
╚══════════════════════════╝
```

Required Output - If Qty is 5 in Table 1 then output should have 5 rows(even if less than 5 rows are present in Table2) 
and each rows should have min ,2nd min , 3rd min , 4th min and 5th min asset respectively.

**Example Output:**

```
╔══════════════════════════╗
║ Item Location Qty Asset  ║
╠══════════════════════════╣
║ 500    Loc1     1     7  ║
║ 500    Loc1     1     8  ║
║ 500    Loc1     1     9  ║
║ 500    Loc1     1     10 ║
║ 500    Loc1     1     11 ║
║ 501    Loc2     1     27 ║
║ 501    Loc2     1        ║
║ 501    Loc3     1        ║
╚══════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried and what output you are getting and then we may be able to help

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 3rd min, 2nd min etc. Is that referring to asset numbers? And what happens if there are *more* than 5 rows in table 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly shorter way:

```
select il.item, il.loc, il.qty, a.asset
from  item_locations il
cross apply ( SELECT rownum rn FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= il.qty ) rn
left outer join lateral 
( SELECT row_Number() over ( order by a.asset) rn, a.asset
  FROM assets a 
  WHERE a.item = il.item and a.loc = il.loc) a ON a.rn = rn.rn;
```

Basically, the `rn` join generates a row for each `qty` value, then we outer join in the assets, based on the sort-position of their asset number.

Full example with data:

```
with item_locations ( item, loc, qty ) AS 
( SELECT 500, 'Loc1', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 501, 'Loc2', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 501, 'Loc3', 1 FROM DUAL ),
assets ( item, loc, qty, asset ) AS (
 SELECT 500,    'Loc1',      1,   11   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 500,    'Loc1',      1,   12   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 500,    'Loc1',      1,   13   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 500,    'Loc1',      1,   14   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 500,    'Loc1',      1,   15   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 500,    'Loc1',      1,   10   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 500,    'Loc1',      1,    9   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 500,    'Loc1',      1,    8   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 500,    'Loc1',      1,    7   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 501,    'Loc2',      1,    27  FROM DUAL )
select il.item, il.loc, il.qty, a.asset
from  item_locations il
cross apply ( SELECT rownum rn FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= il.qty ) rn
left outer join lateral 
( SELECT row_Number() over ( order by a.asset) rn, a.asset
  FROM assets a 
  WHERE a.item = il.item and a.loc = il.loc) a ON a.rn = rn.rn;
```

Results:

```
+------+------+-----+-------+
| ITEM | LOC  | QTY | ASSET |
+------+------+-----+-------+
|  500 | Loc1 |   5 |     7 |
|  500 | Loc1 |   5 |     8 |
|  500 | Loc1 |   5 |     9 |
|  500 | Loc1 |   5 |    10 |
|  500 | Loc1 |   5 |    11 |
|  501 | Loc2 |   2 |    27 |
|  501 | Loc2 |   2 |       |
|  501 | Loc3 |   1 |       |
+------+------+-----+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks! This along with Alex Poole's solution worked for me .

Answer (score 2):

You can use a hierarchical query to convert the `table1` rows into multiple rows based on `qty`:

```
select item, location, qty, level as rn
from table1
connect by level <= qty
and item = prior item
and location = prior location
and prior dbms_random.value is not null;
```

I've included the `level as rn` to use as a fake key later.

You can get an equivalent key value from the `table2` rows using an analytic function; I've assumed your reference to min, 2nd min etc. refer to the order the assets should be shown in, so that column is used for the `order by` clause:

```
select t2.*,
  row_number() over (partition by item, location order by asset) as rn
from table2 t2;
```

Then if you supply both of those as CTE you can outer-join the results:

```
with t1 as (
  select item, location, qty, level as rn
  from table1
  connect by level <= qty
  and item = prior item
  and location = prior location
  and prior dbms_random.value is not null
),
t2 as (
  select t2.*,
    row_number() over (partition by item, location order by asset) as rn
  from table2 t2
)
select t1.item, t1.location, 1 as qty, t2.asset
from t1
left join t2 on t2.item = t1.item and t2.location = t1.location and t2.rn = t1.rn;
```

using the item, locaction *and* the dummy `rn` value from both subqueries above as the combined joing condition.

With your sample data that gets:

```
      ITEM LOCATION        QTY      ASSET
---------- -------- ---------- ----------
       500 Loc1              1          7
       500 Loc1              1          8
       500 Loc1              1          9
       500 Loc1              1         10
       500 Loc1              1         11
       501 Loc2              1         27
       501 Loc2              1           
       501 Loc3              1           

8 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thanks Alex , your solution helped to achieve the result!

Answer (score 0):

Alex and Matthew successfully gave solutions using only SQL.

What I see as an additional solution is **creating a database function** that would **pipe** all the rows you need:

```
TYPE tp_r_item_loc_asset IS RECORD
(
    item        yuor_table_2.item%TYPE,
    location    yuor_table_2.location%TYPE,
    qty         yuor_table_2.qty%TYPE,
    asset       yuor_table_2.asset%TYPE
);

TYPE tp_a_item_loc_asset IS TABLE OF tp_r_item_loc_asset;


FUNCTION f_your_pipeline_funtion
    RETURN tp_a_item_loc_asset
    PIPELINED
IS
    v_row      tp_r_item_loc_asset;
    v_asset    NUMBER := null;  
BEGIN

    FOR i IN (SELECT item, location, qty
                FROM your_table_1
               ORDER BY item, location)
    LOOP

        FOR j in 1..i.qty
        LOOP

            BEGIN
            SELECT asset
              INTO v_asset
              FROM yuor_table_2
             WHERE item = i.item
               AND location = i.location
             ORDER BY asset ASC;

            EXCEPTION
                WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
                THEN
                    v_asset := null;
            END;

            v_row.item      := i.item;
            v_row.location  := i.location;
            v_row.qty       := 1;
            v_row.asset     := v_asset;

        PIPE ROW (v_r_report_blob);

        END LOOP;

    END LOOP;

    RETURN;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    THEN
        RETURN;
END f_your_pipeline_funtion;
```

**Put everything in a package.**

Afterwards, you'd be able to reference it (select from it) via:

```
SELECT item, location, qty, asset
  FROM TABLE (p_your_package_name.f_your_pipeline_funtion());
```

I hope I (also) helped!

Comment: Alex Poole's solution helped to achieve the result!